# (GA4) Bulk User Access mgmt via API ---> GMP management console / User Groups --> GA4 access

Tags: google-analytics-api

we manage GA4 **User Access** mgmt via **Google Marketing Platform management console** --> **User groups** (https://support.google.com/marketingplatform/answer/9013855?hl=en#zippy=%2Cin-this-article)

it’s not possible to bulk manage GA4 access (add/delete user to GA4) via Admin API ?
(GMP management console does not seem to have an API I believe…)

when I use `Method: properties.accessBindings.list` https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/config/admin/v1/rest/v1alpha/properties.accessBindings/list, the response is as follows, as you can see Invalid user ID for users added via GMP management console User Group(I expected User’s Google Account email there)

```
{
      "name": "properties/*********/accessBindings/A********************",
      "user": "Invalid user ID",
      "roles": [
        "predefinedRoles/analyst"
      ]
    }
```

Comment: Did you ever resolve this issue? We would like to use the Admin API to add users to groups for GA4.